# Context is not available in Fragment of another Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, android-gridview

I have an  `Activity` with `DrawerLayout`. I am inflating an `Fragment` in `FrameLayout` of this `Activity` xml file. Xml file contain the `GridView` inside the `LinearLayout`.
I apply `setOnItemClickListener` on this `GridView` inside the fragment `onActivityCreated` method.
But on this method I am calling `AsyncTask` Class of my `Activity`. 
So I am not getting the `Context` when I call this `AsyncTask`  from my `setOnItemClickListener`.
Please give me some suggestion how to do it or any alternative if possible.

**My Activity**

```
class GetExamList extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{
    Context context;

    public GetExamList(Context mContext){
        context=mContext;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {     
     super.onPreExecute();
     pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
     pDialog.setMessage("Fetching Test List");
     pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
     pDialog.setCancelable(true);
     pDialog.show();        
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

         exam_id=1;         
         List<NameValuePair> list = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
         list.add(new BasicNameValuePair("exam_id", exam_id+""));

         JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_exam_list,
                    "POST", list);

        // check for success tag
            try {
                int success = json.getInt("flag");
                Log.d("flag", success+"");                  

                if (success == 1) {
                    //fetch exam list
                    JSONArray elist=json.getJSONArray("testdata");
                    Log.d("flag=1", "in try of HomeExamList");

                    for (int i = 0; i < elist.length(); i++) {

                        JSONObject obj=elist.getJSONObject(i);

                        int testId=obj.getInt("test_id");
                        String testName=obj.getString("test_name");

                        Log.d("elist  test_id", testId+"");
                        Log.d("elist  test_name", testName);

                        Test test=new Test();
                        test.setExam_id(exam_id);
                        test.setTest_id(testId);
                        test.setTest_name(testName);

                        Dao dao=new Dao(context);
                        dao.open();

                        boolean check=dao.chechTestIdInTestList(testId);
                        if(!check)  dao.insertTestList(test);

                        dao.close();
                    }


                } else {
                    // failed to create product
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "unsuccessful", 2000).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     super.onPostExecute(result);
     pDialog.dismiss();

     Intent intent = new Intent(context, ExamList.class);
     intent.putExtra("eid", exam_id);                    
     startActivity(intent);

    }           
}
```

Comment: In Fragement for Context you can use getActivity(), to use Activity's context.

Comment: I can access Context in Fragment but when I call AsyncTask then inside the AsyncTask I am not able to get the Context.

Comment: post your activity main class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are ways to get the context:

If you are in an **Activity**:

```
this;//will call your activity's context
getApplicationContext();//will get the whole application context
```

If you are in a **Fragment**:

```
getActivity();//will call the activity context
```

If you are getting the `context` inside an inner class ex. `Asynctask` in a **Fragment**:

```
Fragment_class_name.this.getActivity();//explicitly get the reference of your fragment and call the context
```

If you are getting the `context` inside an inner class ex. `Asynctask` in a **Activity**:

```
Activity_class_name.this;//explicitly get the reference of your activity context
```

**Edit:**

**change this:**

```
startActivity(intent);
```

**to this:**

```
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: when I pass `Fragment_class_name.this.getActivity();` in AsyncTask constructotr its work for the view initialization but `onPostExecute()` of my AsyncTask I am getting `NullPointerException` when `startActivity(intent)` is called. Debugger Shows `mAction=null`

Comment: @ved post your asynctask ill take a look at it.

Comment: I have added my activity class which have AsyncTAsk class. Now it gives NullPointerException on `startActivity(intent)`.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `getActivity()` is alternative of context in fragment base design.

`getActivity() Return the`Activity` this fragment is currently associated with.

Android docs:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getActivity%28%29

> ((MainActivity) getActivity()) is castable to your Activity.

Comment: I can access Context in Fragment but when I call AsyncTask then inside the AsyncTask I am not able to get the Context.

Comment: You can just passes `getActivity()` instead of `Conetext` this will works.

Comment: I am getting the Context in Fragment from getActivity().But I call AsyncTask call in Fragment and AsyncTask class is defined in MainActivity class. Now in this AsyncTask i am not able to create any view or not able to instantiate databae.

Comment: @ved passed context of activity to constructor of AsyncTask and work with that

Comment: Your question is a little confusing. What are you trying to achieve ? Creating views in an Async task is not typical. Can you elaborate ?

Comment: Why are not passing context to Asyntask you can create view and db with context itself , so you change your asystask. use context instead of activity.

Comment: you can also cast `getActvity()` to your `Activty`, please check my asnwer again i have updated it.

Comment: @LavekushAgrawal it's better to passed context to constructor of `asyncTask` instead of casting, because maybe OP want to use this `asyncTask` class form another activity.

Comment: @shayan pourvatan , that's why i have mention both way in comment as well in answer.

Answer (score 1):

create `private Context mContext`;

```
mContext=getActivity();
```

now you can use `mContext` instead of `getActivity()`;